# How to convert 25:30:40 to minutes

Tags: excel, vba

How to convert 25:30:40 to minutes in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TimeSerial`:

```vb
TextTime = "25:30:40"
Minutes = DateDiff("n", #00:00#, TimeSerial(Split(TextTime, ":")(0), Split(TextTime, ":")(1), Split(TextTime, ":")(2)))
? Minutes 
 1530
```